# module flask will not launch

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

[project interpreter and local env IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB5Qj.png)I'm having a real problem with using the module flask , I've tried a lot of the solutions here on the forum but none has worked.

I can see flask is installed 
pip list - showing flask
in the setting the module flask is installed in project interpreter 
when I type the code I can see the module comes up

However when I launch the code I get an error

> No module named 'flask'

I've tried to re-install pycharm
I've tried to uninstall and install flask again
still the same problem. Any advice ?

The file name vsearch.py

Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, escape

app = Flask(__name__)

def search4words(phrase: str, letters: str) -> set:
    return set(letters).intersection(set(phrase))

def log_request(req: 'flask_request', res: str) -> None:
    with open('vsearch.log', 'a') as log:
        print(req.form, req.remote_addr, req.user_agent, res, file=log, 
        sep='|')

@app.route('/search4', methods=['POST'])
def do_search() -> 'html':
    phrase = request.form['phrase']
    letters = request.form['letters']
    title = 'Here are your results:'
    results = str(search4words(phrase, letters))
    log_request(request, results)
    return render_template('results.html', the_phrase=phrase, 
                           the_letters=letters, the_title=title, 
                           the_results=results,)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/entry')
def entry_page() -> 'html':
    return render_template('entry.html', the_title='Welcome back 
    AGAIN!!!!!')

@app.route('/viewlog')
def view_the_log() -> 'html':
    contents = []
    with open('vsearch.log') as log:
        for line in log:
            contents.append([])
            for item in line.split('|'):
                 contents[-1].append(escape(item))
    titles = ('Form Data', 'Remote_addr', 'User_agent', 'Results')
    return render_template('viewlog.html',
                           the_title = 'View log',
                           the_row_titles = titles,
                           the_data = contents,)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you please post your code and the file name you are trying to execute?

Comment: Yes of course just give me a minute. the code is working as it has been working before and nothing changed

Comment: I've even tried to do a simple hello world file but still writes the same

Comment: I copied your code and executed it using `pycharm`. It's working fine for me.

Comment: i know the code is working fine buddy , the question here is why the Local is writting No module flask when its installed everywhere. The code IS WORKING i know this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue was attempting to run `vsearch.py` through terminal, rather than through PyCharm's interpreter (which was correctly installed). In order to utilize the virtual environment, you should configure it to be used correctly when running your code.

There are multiple ways of activating your virtual environment, so please find that which is applicable to your project. A good source for this would be https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/26/python-virtual-env/.

Comment: i've already mentioned in the post ' the module flask is installed in project interpreter '

Comment: I see flask there, the project was setup from new in a new directory when i've re-installed pycharm, then i manually copied and pasted all the files from the original project. I see - Flask, jinja2, click, markupsafe, werkzeug, itsdangerous, mysql, mysqlclient, pip and setuptools

Comment: My mistake, I must have missed it reading your question the first time. I will keep thinking and delete my answer if I do not find any applicable answers.

Comment: @Genx505 I don't have enough reputation to comment on the original post. Would you be able to try changing "import flask ..." to "import Flask ..." in your code and running it for me?

Comment: No luck buddy , code comes up and in red and when i try to run it same issue no moudle named 'Flask' , the weirdest part about it when i start typing from fl ... he shows the option of flask module, so pycharm can see the module otherwise he wouldnt suggest it when you start typing from fl...

Comment: @Genx505 would you be able to add `print(help("modules flask"))` to the beginning of your code and share the output?

Comment: Ok this is getting freaking weird now , i've tried to run the whole code through python console and it has worked. Now the question remains why the hell its not booting the code through terminal

Comment: flask - flask
flask.__main__ - flask.__main__
flask._compat - flask._compat
flask.app - flask.app
flask.blueprints - flask.blueprints
flask.cli - flask.cli
flask.config - flask.config
flask.ctx - flask.ctx
flask.debughelpers - flask.debughelpers
flask.globals - flask.globals
flask.helpers - flask.helpers
flask.json - flask.json
flask.json.tag - Tagged JSON
flask.logging - flask.logging
flask.sessions - flask.sessions
flask.signals - flask.signals
flask.templating - flask.templating
flask.testing - flask.testing
flask.views - flask.views
flask.wrappers - flask.wrappers

Comment: None
 * Serving Flask app "<input>" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat

Comment: Running the code through terminal will utilize whichever python version your OS prefers, on Mac this is the preinstalled version 2.7. I am not versed enough in virtual environments to be able to help you, but I will edit my answer to match that.

Comment: no worries bud thanks anyway, i've decided ill just uninstall python and pycharm and re-install fresh and see if it help

Comment: Fresh install of pycharm and python 3.7.3 resolved the issue , still no clue to what was the issue.